# How to print only some characters in C?

Tags: c

I have an array:

```
char arr[]="This is the string";
```

For instance, if I want to print only first 5 characters of that string, I have tried the following:

```
printf("%-5s",arr);
```

But it is printing whole string. Why?

Comment: `"%-5s"` is just a string formatter. It does not truncate the string.

Comment: use precision. Google precision for printf.

Comment: @xing are you sure about `.-` syntax? AFAIR, `-` is a flag...so...

Comment: `printf("%.5s",arr);` but the fifth character is a space so it will look like four.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-` is a printf formater for *justification*, not *precision*.

What you want is the `.` formater which is used for precision :

```
printf("%.5s", arr);
```

This will print the first 5 elements of `arr`.

If you want to learn more about printf formaters, take a look at [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `%.*s`, it takes size of intended bytes to be printed and pointer to char as arguments when using with `printf`. For example,

```
// It prints This
printf("%.*s", 4, arr);
```

> But it is printing whole string. Why?

You are using `%-5s` meaning the `-` left-justifies your text in that field.

---

En passant, the output cannot be achieved by using the accepted answer as simply as the code snippet, even if it may be seemed derisively.

```
int i;
char arr[]="This is the string";

for (i = 1; i < sizeof(arr); ++i) {
    printf("%.*s\n", i, arr);
}
```

Output:

```
T
Th
Thi
This
This 
This i
This is
This is 
This is t
This is th
This is the
This is the 
This is the s
This is the st
This is the str
This is the stri
This is the strin
This is the string
```

Comment: Really nice to use of `*` to allow dynamic choose of number of characters to display

Comment: Yes, using precision between the quotations sometimes is not good because what if I want to change its value consistently in a `for loop` or by with macro definition`#define ....` like that @Garf365

Answer (score 0):

for example substring extraction function (extracts substring to the buff)

```
char *strpart(char *str, char *buff, int start, int end)
{
    int len = str != NULL ? strlen(str) : -1 ;
    char *ptr = buff;

    if (start > end || end > len - 1 || len == -1 || buff == NULL) return NULL;

    for (int index = start; index <= end; index++)
    {
        *ptr++ = *(str + index);
    }
    *ptr = '\0';
    return buff;
}
```

Comment: I think this solution is not the desired in this case

Comment: @horro why? he wants to print **some** part of the string as the title states.

Comment: Engineer who makes best things by using minimum stock.

Comment: It's a sledgehammer to crack a nut here

Answer (score 0):

You can do it quite simply in a number of ways. With a loop, looping the number of times desired, picking off chars each time, you can walk a pointer down the string an temporary nul-terminate after the 5th character, or you can simply use `strncpy` to copy 5 chars to a buffer and print that. (that is probably the simplest), e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char arr[]="This is the string",
        buf[sizeof arr] = "";      /* note: nul-termination via initialization */

    strncpy (buf, arr, 5);

    printf ("'%s'\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strncpy
'This '
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Extra memory consumer :)

Comment: Yup - memory hog (all 13 bytes `:)`